# Unity3D - A* Pathfinding Jittering Movement

Tags: c#, path-finding, unity-game-engine

I am using [arongranberg](http://arongranberg.com) A* Pathfinding for my project. 
Basically the enemy will follow my player if I am too close to him.

[image: Jittering Movement]

As you can see here the enemy's (blue guy) movement is not as smooth as what I expected.

Below is the code for movement detection and dynamic Path Request.

```
void checkPosition(){
    currentPosition = transform.position;
    if (previousPosition == null) {
        previousPosition = transform.position;
    } 
    else {

        if (currentPosition.x > previousPosition.x) {
            moveRight ();
        } else if (currentPosition.x < previousPosition.x) {
            moveLeft ();
        }
        if (currentPosition.y > previousPosition.y) {
            moveUp ();
        } else if (currentPosition.y < previousPosition.y) {
            moveDown ();
        } else if (currentPosition.x == previousPosition.x && currentPosition.y == previousPosition.y) {
            //stopNow ();
        }
        previousPosition = currentPosition;
    }
}


IEnumerator UpdatePath(){
    seeker.StartPath(transform.position, target.position, OnPathComplete);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f/updateRate);
    StartCoroutine (UpdatePath ());     
}
```

What can I do to improve it ?

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with the pathing?  Have you tried setting a breakpoint on the code that makes the enemy turn around and see where/why it's being called?

Comment: I am sure, because the other character that were not supposed to follow me yet are required to do strolling action, which I am using waypoints. While strolling the animation and movement are doing just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that MoveDown/Up/Left/Right does not make you overlap the target ? If it happends, then your seeker could "go back" the next frame. If it's the case, a basic distance condition before applying the seeker's move could resolve this issue